# Is there, in Aristotle, a broad concept of thinking ( noèsis) that includes imagination ? Or is imagination a purely sensible power?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy, aristotle, psychology

- In Aristotle's *De Anima*, Bk. III, Part 3 ( http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/soul.3.iii.html) one can read this :

"Thinking is different from perceiving and is held to be in part imagination, in part judgement: we must therefore first mark off the sphere of imagination and then speak of judgement. If then imagination is that in virtue of which an image arises for us, excluding metaphorical uses of the term, is it a single faculty or disposition relative to images, in virtue of which we discriminate and are either in error or not? The faculties in virtue of which we do this are sense, opinion, science, intelligence"

( which translates this : " Περὶ δὲ τοῦ ***νοεῖ***ν, ἐπεὶ ἕτερον τοῦ αἰσθάνεσθαι, τούτου δὲ τὸ μὲν ***φαντασία*** δοκεῖ εἶναι τὸ δὲ ***ὑπόληψις***, περὶ φαντασίας διορίσαντας οὕτω περὶ θατέρου λεκτέον.")

- So ***Aristotle seems to subsume explicitly imagination under the genus  " thinking*** " ( noein, noèsis) and to distinguish 2 species in this  genus : (1) imagination ( phantasia) and (2) judgment ( *upolepsis*) .

However, in Aquinas' commentary on De Anima, one reads that imagination belongs to sensibility, inasmuch as it s a movement caused by the movement of sense.

- Do modern commentators challenge Aquinas' reading?

Is the passage I quote an exception, or ***does Aristotle actually has a broad concept of " thinking" which includes imagination?***

Comment: "Aristotle’s account of  phantasia  in  De Anima  3.3 is notoriously difficult to decipher", so begins a recent paper that mentions (note2) some 14 studies   before launching its own theses; see Scheiter, Phronesis 57 (2012) 251-278 online.pdf https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/muse.union.edu/dist/9/93/files/2012/10/Images-Appearances-and-Phantasia-in-Aristotle.pdf

Comment: In the paragraph right above this quote he writes:"*For imagination is different from either perceiving or discursive thinking, though it is not found without sensation, or judgement without it.*" Just because *noesis* is "*in part imagination, in part judgement*" does not mean that either is subsumed under it. Water is in part hydrogen and in part oxygen, but neither of them is subsumed under "water".

Comment: Also, this translation is terrible, see [Green, p.5](https://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Aristotle/De-anima/de-anima3.htm):"*That imagination is not the same as thinking (noesis, νόησις) and supposing (hupolepsis) is clear. For that affection (τὸ
πάθος) [imagination] is up to us when we wish...
but opinioning (δοξάζειν) is not up to us*".